# How do I express that a point $A$ has coordinates $(a, b)$, symbolically? $ $ Should I just write $A=(a, b)$?

Tags: notation, coordinate-systems

How do I express that a point $A$ has coordinates $(a, b)$, symbolically? $ $
Should I just write $A=(a, b)$, or there's a better way? $ $  Also, if $B$ has coordinates (c+1, d+2), and I know $A$ and $B$ have the same coordinates, can I write $(a, b)=(c+1, d+2)$?

Comment: All the proposed examples look fine to me.

Comment: I would${{{}}}$.

Comment: Your way looks fine to me. Stewart (the calculus behemoth) uses the weird A(a,b) fwiw

Comment: Okay great. Merci!

Comment: By all means stick to your usage. When I see $A(3,4)$ instead of $A=(3,4)$ **it gives me the creeps**. After all, $A(3,4)$ is a *mathematical object* (and I then want to know the definition of the function $A(\cdot,\cdot)$), whereas $A=(3,4)$ expresses a *statement*, as is  intended by the writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common expression is $A:=(a,b)$ where the symbol "$:=$" means "defined as". Of course it is also common just write $A=(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the following notation; suppose $x\in X$ belongs to an abstract   2-dimensional space. By virtue of being two-dimensional, it has a basis $E$ of 2 elements, say $E = (e_1,e_2)$. Then there exists two numbers $a,b$ such that $x = aE_1 + bE_2$. We then define 
$$ [E, x]:= \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$$
This notation makes it clear that there is a choice of basis.